# MySQL: GROUP BY устовия для COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

Как задать максимальный и минимальный размеры группы, чтобы получить записи, где `count < 5` и `count > 2`?

На данный момент использую такой запрос:

```
SELECT id, info, COUNT(*) as count
FROM notification
GROUP BY info ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Пример:

```
+----+-------+
| id |  info |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Admin |
|  2 |  User |
|  3 |  User |
|  4 |  User |
|  5 |  User |
|  6 |  User |
|  7 | Admin |
|  8 | Admin |
|  9 | Test  |
| 10 | Test  |
+----+-------+
```

Желаемый вывод:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id |  info |  count |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | Admin |      3 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте параметр [`HAVING`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)):

```
SELECT id, info, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM notification 
GROUP BY info
HAVING count(*) > 2
       and count(*) < 5
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c042/1/0).

Answer (score 3):

Если таблица большая, то правильнее будет обернуть в другой запрос и написать условие в where. Работать будет быстрее.

```
SELECT * FROM   (
                SELECT id, info, COUNT(*) as count 
                FROM notification 
                GROUP BY info
                ) a
WHERE a.count > 2 AND a.count < 5
```